# Oracle Forms Builder Ubuntu Installition issues

Tags: linux, oracle, forms, builder

I try to install Oracle Forms and Builder 12.2.

I have already Oracle SQL Developer. And I'm sure that I downloaded the appropriate .zip file (64bit, Linux).

But before the installation, I have some problems and they affect the progress of installation if I ignore them.

Screenshot of problems in here:[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think you should describe effect of these warnings

Answer (score 0):

The operating system on which you are installing is not in the certified list for the Oracle forms builder 12.2
For dependency rpm list and kernel parameters refer the oracle installation document.
Ignoring dependency packages will cause problems after/during installation. 
Hope this helps!